# How can I submit documents to Apple as reject for use of protected 3rd party material?

Tags: iphone, submit, document

I've received a rejected:

> 8.5: Use of protected 3rd party material (trademarks, copyrights, trade secrets, otherwise proprietary content) requires a documented rights check which must be provided upon request

I've got the document now but after I upload my app, and I can not find any place to submit my document. Is there anybody that knowns how to submit it?

I knew that before I upload my app I can submit the document, but I want to know how to submit my document after I have already upload my app.

Answer (score 1):

One idea: tell them you have the documentation in the review notes.  In iTunes Connect, click on your app.  Then click the View Details button.  Then click the Edit button next to “Version Information”.  In the “Review Notes” text box, tell them that you have the documentation and will provide it on request.  Or put the documentation on a web server somewhere and enter the URL.

Another idea: [Submit an appeal to the app review board](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewboard/index.html), and tell them you have the documentation in the “Reasons for Appealing” text box.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you ideas and do you have any other way to submit my documentation directly

Comment: I gave you all the ideas I have.  There might be other ways, but unfortunately I don't know everything.